# How to export the data of a pivot table ( of an existing excel sheets) to multiple excel sheets

Tags: python-2.7

I am bit new to python and implementing a project to convert an excel sheet to pivot table excel sheet, and then once the pivot table excel sheet is created, I am trying to create multiple excel sheet for each pivot data ( each row of the pivot data )

I am succesful in getting till the pivot data in excel ( Workbook3.xlsx ), but from here, if i am trying to go for a "for loop", I am getting below error :

"*raise NotImplementedError("Writing as Excel with a MultiIndex is "
NotImplementedError: Writing as Excel with a MultiIndex is not yet implemented*."

Can someone help me out to implement this last step ?

Below is my code :

## Author : Abhishek

## Version : December 23, 2016

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np

names=['Business Type','Trip ID','Status','Name of Customer','Driver Name','Trip Type','One way/two way','Channel of Lead','Payment Rate','Remark for Payment/Discount/Fixed Rate/Monthly Rate','Trip Date','Trip ID','Entry Date and Time','CSE','Trip Time(when customer required)','Begin Trip Time','End Trip Time','Hours','Minutes','Basic','Basics','Transit','Transits','Discount ','Discounts','Tax','Total','Wallet','Wallet Type','Cash with Driver','Adjustment','Remark','Blank','Basic','Zuver (20%)','Basic Earning','Transit','Total Earning','Cash Colleted','Balance','Inventive','Total Earning','Total Cash Collected','Total Balance','Total Incentive','Final Invoice']
df=pd.read_excel(r'path/28 Nov - 4 Dec _ Payment IC _ Mumbai.xlsx',sheetname='calc',header=None,names=names)
df = df[df.Status != 'Cancelled']
df = df[df.Status != 'Unfulfilled']

#print df['Begin Trip Time'].values

# Defining variables for the output Report

custname=df['Name of Customer'].values
drivername=df['Driver Name'].values
drivercontact=df['Trip Date'].values
status=df['Status'].values
tripstatus=df['Begin Trip Time'].values
triptype=df['End Trip Time'].values
starttime=df['Hours'].values
endtime=df['Minutes'].values
transit=df['Transits'].values
totalbill=df['Basic Earning'].values
totalearning=df['Transits'].values+df['Basic Earning'].values
cashcollected=df['Cash Colleted'].values
balance=df['Balance'].values
incentive= df['Inventive'].values

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(totalbill,drivername,custname,drivercontact,status,tripstatus,triptype,starttime,endtime,totalbill,transit,totalearning,cashcollected,balance,incentive))

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('path/Workbook2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False,header=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()

#Pivot table
df2=pd.read_excel(r'path/Workbook2.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')

#table=pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['Driver Name','Name of Customer'])
df2['Inventive'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, values=['Hours', 'Minutes'],index=['Driver Name','Name of Customer','Inventive','Trip Date','Status','Begin Trip Time','End Trip Time','Basic Earning','Cash Colleted','Balance'],aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value='0', margins=True)
pivoted = pd.ExcelWriter('path/Workbook3.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df2.to_excel(pivoted, sheet_name='Sheet1')
pivoted.save()

df3=pd.read_excel(r'path/Workbook3.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')
        
for n in range(0, len(df3)):
    tempdata=df3.iloc[n]
    df4= pd.DataFrame(tempdata)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter('path/Final%s.xlsx' % n, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet 1')
    writer.save()
```